# Check/Uncheck checkbox depend on value match

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we get a checkbox checked only if a dynamic value matches the checkbox value in one line without applying if condition. otherwise uncheck checkbox,.

```js
var checkVal = 'red';
$('#black:input[value="'+checkVal+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="black" id="black" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="black">
    Black
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use the `!=` in your selector? e.g. `$('input[type="checkbox"][value!="'+checkVal+'"]').prop('checked', false);`

Comment: Given that you have an ID, you can just utilise that ID: `$("#black").prop("checked", $("#black").val() == checkVal)` which will check or uncheck (as a one-liner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare the value in your prop:

```js
var checkVal = 'red';
var $element = $('#black');
$element.prop('checked', $element.val() === checkVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="black" id="black" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="black">
    Black
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`!=` as per @DarkBee works here, something I didn't know as well.

```js
var checkVal = 'red';
$('input[value!="'+checkVal+'"]').prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="black" id="black" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="black">
    Black
  </label>
</div>
```

```js
var checkVal = 'black';
$('input[value="'+checkVal+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="black" id="black" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="black">
    Black
  </label>
</div>
```